# Make variable equal value in function

Tags: php, arrays, function, var

I have a function in a language file which which stores an array of text. I'm also trying to create a variable to equal a particular value in that array.

here's my function...

```
    function Day_1_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'TEXT1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'TEXT2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}
```

here's my var being assigned the value within the function...

```
$day1Txt = Day_1_Offer('EMAIL_OFFER');
```

The error i get is...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Day_1_Offer() in
```

This is the complete language.php file...

```
function Day_1_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_2_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_3_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_4_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_5_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_6_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}

function Day_7_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'Text1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'Text2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}
```

If anyone knows of a more efficient way of doing this then would be grateful to see it.

Comment: Did you included this file, where this `Day_1_Offer` is? I bet no.

Comment: That error means you did no included that function at your script.

Comment: I included like this <? include 'language/language.php'; ?>

Comment: it works when i do this `echo Day_1_Offer('SITE_OFFER');`

Comment: but doesn't work when i do this `$day1Txt = Day_1_Offer('EMAIL_OFFER');`

Comment: If you do both of those at the same place, they should both work. You probably have a typo in the assignment version.

Comment: This whole approach seems wrong. Why not just create a 2-dimensional array, and do `$txt = $offers[$day]['EMAIL_OFFER']`?

Comment: i thought there might be a better way of doing this but wasn't sure how, thanks i'll have a go.

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your library file where fucntion is defined

my_fun.php

```
function Day_1_Offer($day){
    static $offer = array(
        'SITE_OFFER' => 'TEXT1', //Offer text for front end
        'EMAIL_OFFER' => 'TEXT2' //Offer text for hidden form field
    );
    return $offer[$day];
}
```

And this is the file where you are using it

index.php

```
include 'my_fun.php';
$day1Txt = Day_1_Offer('EMAIL_OFFER');
```

You need to use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for this

Comment: `require`, `require_once` and `include_once` can be used in place of `incude`. but yeah, you need one of them.

Comment: still throws the error on this line `$day1Txt = Day_1_Offer('EMAIL_OFFER');`